# How to test an NGRX effect that uses a store selector?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an `@Effect` that uses a `MemoizedSelector` to grab an item from the redux store and `mergeMap` it with the payload of an Action. The effect works just fine, however setting up the Jest tests for this has proven difficult as I cannot seem to mock the return value of the selector due to `select` being a declared function that's imported (from **'@ngrx/store'**) and used in the effect and the selector itself being an imported function as well. I'm grasping at straws now.

How can I write a Unit Test to test an NGRX effect that makes use of a store selector?
**"@ngrx/store": "^7.4.0"**,
**"rxjs": "^6.2.2"**

#### I have tried the following kinds of solutions:

1. using

```
provideMockStore({
  initialState
})
```

**provideMockStore** comes in from `'@ngrx/store/testing';` where initial state was both my *actual* initialState and a state that contains the exact structure/item I'm trying to select

2. using different types of `MockStore`'s from various SO questions/answers as well as different blog posts approaches

   - [Mock ngrx store selectors in unit tests (Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737456/mock-ngrx-store-selectors-in-unit-tests-angular)
   - https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-i-test-my-ngrx-selectors-c50b1dc556bc
   - https://christianlydemann.com/the-complete-guide-to-ngrx-testing/
   - https://medium.com/@adrianfaciu/testing-ngrx-effects-3682cb5d760e
3. attempting to mock the selector using `<selector>.projector(<my-mock-object>)` (straw-grasping here, I'm pretty sure this would be used in isolated testing of the *selector* not the Effect)

The Effect itself:

```
@Effect()
  getReviewsSuccess$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<ProductActions.GetReviewsSuccess>(
      ProductActions.ProductActionTypes.GET_REVIEWS_SUCCESS
    ),
    mergeMap(() => this.reduxStore.pipe(select(selectProduct))),
    map(({ product_id }) => product_id),
    map(product_id => new ProductActions.GetReviewsMeta({
      product_id,
    }))
  );
```

The Spec:

```
......
  let effects: ProductEffects;
  let facade: Facade;
  let actions$: Observable<any>;
  let store$: Observable<State>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        // ^ I've also tried using StoreModule.forRoot(...) here to configure 
        // it in similar fashion to the module where this effect lives
      ],
      providers: [
        ProductEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions$),
        {
          provide: Facade,
          useValue: facadeServiceMock,
        },
        ResponseService,
        provideMockStore({
          initialState
        })
        // ^ also tried setting up the test with different variations of initialState
      ],
    });
......

it('should return a GetReviewsMeta on successful GetReviewsSuccess', () => {
    const reviews = {...reviewListMock};
    const { product_id } = {...productMockFull};

    const action = new ProductActions.GetReviewsSuccess({
      reviews
    });

    const outcome = new ProductActions.GetReviewsMeta({
      product_id
    });

    actions$ = hot('-a', { a: action }); 

    // store$ = cold('-c', { c: product_id });  
    // not sure what, if anything I need to do here to mock select(selectProduct)  

    const expected = cold('-b', { b: outcome });  
    expect(effects.getReviewsSuccess$).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
```

The Selector `selectProduct`:

```
export const getProduct = ({product}: fromProducts.State) => product;

export const getProductState = createFeatureSelector<
    fromProducts.State
>('product');

export const selectProduct = createSelector(
  getProductState,
  getProduct,
);
```

I expect the test to pass but instead I keep getting the following error

```
● Product Effects › should return a GetReviewsMeta on successful GetReviewsSuccess

    expect(received).toBeNotifications(expected)

    Expected notifications to be:
      [{"frame": 10, "notification": {"error": undefined, "hasValue": true, "kind": "N", "value": {"payload": {"product_id": 2521}, "type": "[Reviews] Get Reviews Meta"}}}]
    But got:
      [{"frame": 10, "notification": {"error": [TypeError: Cannot read property 'product_id' of undefined], "hasValue": false, "kind": "E", "value": undefined}}]
```

Clearly the `MemoizedSelector` (selectProduct) doesn't know what the Product Object is that should be in the store (but doesn't seem to be whether I inject an `initialState` that has it or not) and can't get the `product_id` of the Product because I didn't set this up correctly in the `beforeEach` or in the spec itself...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We got this covered in the [ngrx.io](https://next.ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing#effects-that-use-state) docs. Note that the syntax is for NgRx 8 but the same ideas count for NgRx 7.

```
addBookToCollectionSuccess$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(CollectionApiActions.addBookSuccess),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromBooks.getCollectionBookIds))),
        tap(([, bookCollection]) => {
          if (bookCollection.length === 1) {
            window.alert('Congrats on adding your first book!');
          } else {
            window.alert('You have added book number ' + bookCollection.length);
          }
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

```
it('should alert number of books after adding the second book', () => {
      store.setState({
        books: {
          collection: {
            loaded: true,
            loading: false,
            ids: ['1', '2'],
          },
        },
      } as fromBooks.State);

      const action = CollectionApiActions.addBookSuccess({ book: book1 });
      const expected = cold('-c', { c: action });
      actions$ = hot('-a', { a: action });
      expect(effects.addBookToCollectionSuccess$).toBeObservable(expected);
      expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('You have added book number 2');
    });
  });
```

Make sure that your state has the same structure as in the redux devtools.

NgRx 8 also provides a way to mock selectors, so it isn't needed to set up the whole state tree for a single test - https://next.ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-mock-selectors.

```
describe('Auth Guard', () => {
  let guard: AuthGuard;
  let store: MockStore<fromAuth.State>;
  let loggedIn: MemoizedSelector<fromAuth.State, boolean>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [AuthGuard, provideMockStore()],
    });

    store = TestBed.get(Store);
    guard = TestBed.get(AuthGuard);

    loggedIn = store.overrideSelector(fromAuth.getLoggedIn, false);
  });

  it('should return false if the user state is not logged in', () => {
    const expected = cold('(a|)', { a: false });

    expect(guard.canActivate()).toBeObservable(expected);
  });

  it('should return true if the user state is logged in', () => {
    const expected = cold('(a|)', { a: true });

    loggedIn.setResult(true);

    expect(guard.canActivate()).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```

Comment: aaaahhh, it somehow did not occur to me to look in the docs for the beta! I kept rooting around in the current stable or looking at previous versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My apologies for missing the beta documentation. I had not correctly emulated the state in the `initialState`!