# What causes "Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated"?

Tags: angular, testing

here is my test :

```js
describe('ValueService', () => {

  it('#getValue should return real value', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And I have this error :

> Failed: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject` before `R3TestBed.configureTestingModule`.
> Error: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject` before `R3TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

Comment: please add the complete spec file content

Comment: Hi Saroste, just a friendly tip, use the CODE button to add code, it will help a lot to people reading your posts and help will be more probable.

Comment: Thanks mrbarletta
@GérômeGrignon i only have this in my spec file.

Comment: Is it the only test with a focus with 'fdescribe' ? It sounds like you have a another test with missing dependencies begin triggered too by karma.

Comment: Yes @GérômeGrignon it's the only one. How can i identify the test with missing dependencies?

Comment: I would search for a class having RechercheService and DroitsObligatiosnService inside its constructor

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As discussed with the author, the problem arise when the `TestBed` is initialized outside a `describe` when having two spec files or more.

For example:

```ts
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
 });
```

will instanciate a `TestBed` beforeEach tests, not only the spec file. Hence, if you have another .spec with a TestBed and a beforeEach it will be interpreted as 2 TestBed instanciated like this:

```ts
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
 });
```

The error

> Failed: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has
> already been instantiated.

will be right, since you instanciate two TestBed (but in two spec files).

To solve this problem, you must always put the `TestBed` definition (so the `beforeEach`) in a describe like this:

```ts
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Please note that you may experience this error if the following conditions are true, even if you properly have your `TestBed.configureTestingModule` inside a `describe`:

1. Your project is on Angular 13+
2. You are using NgRx
3. You are using `provideMockStore` in your test.

This issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3243).

The fix is to add `teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }` to your module configuration.

Comment: This was the answer I needed - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This may also happen when we use a describe inside another describe as show below

```
describe('parent suite',()=>{
beforeEach(()=>{
// configure Testing module
// and some injections
})
// some tests....
describe('child suite',()=>{

beforeEach(()=>{
// here in parent suite if we perform any injections we have to use **TestBed.resetTestingModule()** before configuring another testing module`enter code here`
})


})
})
Hope this helps..
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was exactly the issue I was having.