# Testing arguments in to store.select using jasmine on deprecated ngrx selectors with props

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-selectors

I maintain/develop a angular web-app that uses a lot of ngrx selectors with props.

After upgrading it from Angular v9 to v13, I have had to refactor these selectors, because [RFC: Deprecate Selectors With Props](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980) deprecated NGRX's selectors with props, in favour of factory selectors. This refactoring was pretty straight-forward, but it has had an impact on the testing.

In particular, I cannot make work jasmine tests that previously worked checking how the selectors with props were called. Before, testing what arguments were passed to the store.select function was possible like this:

```js
spyOn(store, 'select');
expect(store.select).toHaveBeenCalledWith( selectorWithPropsFnName, Props );
```

But now, when the above syntax is update to cope with the new ngrx selectors approach to this:

```js
spyOn(store, 'select');
expect(store.select).toHaveBeenCalledWith( selectorWithPropsFnName(Props) );
```

the test fails with the error message:

`Expected [ Function ] to equal [ Function ].`

Can anyone shed some light on how one is supposed to test this now?

Thanks!

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737456/mock-ngrx-store-selectors-with-parameters-in-unit-tests-angular/70554519#70554519

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AakashGoplani. That allows me to mock the output of the selector, but what I need is to see which properties arrived at the selector in the original call. It seems like it should, but I can't seem to make it work. I feel like we are close :-D. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We can use like following will help you out.

#declare store at primary describe level

```
let store: MockStore;
```

#add provider at TestBed Configuaration

```
provideMockStore({initialState: {}}),
```

#get injected mock store

```
store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
```

#mock selectors

#store.ovverideSelector(selectorName,value);

#example

```
store.ovverrideSelector(selectUserId, '1');
```