# How to mock ngrx factory selector in testing usng jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using ngrx store for state management and writing test cases for a component which is using a factory selector and in the test cases i need to pass a mock data

cutomer.selector.ts

```
export const selectCustomer = (id: string) =>
createSelector(selectCustomers, (customers) => customers[id]);
```

customer.component.ts

```
 const data = this.store.select(selectCustomer(3));
```

the problem is that there is no documentation provided for mocking the factory selector . so i can test it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `MockStore` from `'@ngrx/store/testing'`?

There is a similar question answered here: [how to mock ngrx selector in a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288024/how-to-mock-ngrx-selector-in-a-component?rq=2)

Their solution:

```
imports { ... } from '...';
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let store: MockStore<AppState>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      imports: [
            ...
      ],
      providers: [
          ...
          provideMockStore({initialState}),
        
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    store.overrideSelector(mySelector, {
      id: 0,
      name: 'test',
      value: 50,
    })
    fixture.detectChanges();
    spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callFake(() => {});
  });
});
```

The official documentation: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-mock-selectors

Comment: You can't use `overrideSelector` with factory selectors. You can however use the mock store and populate it with data that the selector depends on, and test the selector's resulting output.

Comment: It seems to be possible in some cases https://github.com/ngrx/platform/discussions/3279#discussioncomment-5012453 but anyway there already is a whole discution on their github about how to handle factory selectors in test https://github.com/ngrx/platform/discussions/3279